# what dose exactly Vs code debug console command line at bottom do ? How to use it

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

[image]

This command line at bottom of Vs code what dose exactly do? how its useful
I had searched a lot but I cant figured out what is it and I can't find any documentation about, and last question I'm flutter dev how can I use it at debug process.

Comment: Run the app on debug mode, you will find it out

Comment: I'm not pushing to close-vote but a question like this is more on-topic on https://superuser.com/

Comment: had are serious? man I know how to debug but whats it dose ? I want to know the usage

Answer (score 1):

Let’s say that you hit a breakpoint with a httpresponse while debuging, and you want to know whats in it you can call httpresponse.body etc. In the command line to see whats in the body.